# "Advanced Options" module fieldset in Joomla 2.5 and 3.x

Tags: joomla, joomla2.5, joomla-extensions, joomla3.0, joomla-module

In my module's xml file, I have a fieldset for ADVANCED OPTIONS like this:

```
<fieldset name="advanced">
    <field .... />
    <field .... />
    <field .... />          
</fieldset>
```

In Joomla 2.5, the ADVANCED OPTIONS of my module correctly shows all the fields as described in the xml.

However in Joomla 3.x, the ADVANCED OPTIONS shows all the fields from the xml file plus some extra options. Even if I totally remove this fieldset, it still shows the ADVANCED OPTIONS with some default fields.

How do I make sure both Joomla 2.5 and 3.x have the same ADVANCED OPTIONS?

Comment: What are these "extra options" that are being displayed for you?

Comment: @Lodder The extra options are `Module Tag`, `Bootstrap Size`, `Header Tag`, `Header Class` and `Module Style`.

Comment: The are added by default by Joomla for all modules, so not to worry about them ;)

Comment: @Lodder That's good for Joomla 3.x but how do I display `Header Tag`, for instance, in Joomla 2.5? I just need to make sure `Header Tag` option appears in both Joomla 2.5 and 3.x.

Comment: header tag is not an option for Joomla 2.5. It was introduced in Joomla 3.x